# Integral and numeric optimization (nlminb) R

Tags: r, optimization, numerical-methods

I am having issues with an optimization problem involving numerical estimation of an integral which contains an unknown variable.

Numerical estimating an integral is simple enough, just use the integrate function in R. I am trying to estimate a rather unpleasant integral which requires optimization since it contains an unknown variable and a constraint. I am using the nlminb function but the result is highly incorrect. The idea is to evaluate the integral to constraint smaller or equal to 1-l, where l is between 0 and 1.

the code is the following:

```
integrand <- function(x, p) {dnorm(x,0,1)*(1-dnorm((qnorm(p)
                            -sqrt(0.12)*x)/(sqrt(1-0.12)), 0, 1))^800}
```

and it is the variable p which is unknown.

The objective function to be minimised is the following:

```
objective <- function(p){

  PoD <- integrate(integrand, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf, p = p)$value  

  PoD - 0.5
}

test <- nlminb(0.015, objective = objective, lower = 0, upper = 1)$par*100
```

Edited to reflect mistakes in the objective function and the integral.
Same issue still remains.

I think my mistake is not specifying which variable to minimise. The optimisation just gives the starting value in nlminb multiplied by 100.

The authors of the paper used dummy variables and showed that a l = 0,5 should give p=0,15%.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, since your objective function does not depend on `p`. Do:

```
integrand <- function(x, p) {dnorm(x,0,1)*(1-dnorm((qnorm(p)
                           -sqrt(0.12)*x)/(sqrt(1-0.12)), 0, 1))^800}

objective <- function(p){

  PoD <- integrate(integrand, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf, p = p)$value  

  PoD - 0.5
}
```

Comment: The issue still remains that the optimisation in nmlinb still results in the starting value multiplied by 100.

Comment: @Mikkelborchsenius You probably miscopied my code. I find `0.8518969` (*100).

Comment: would it be possible to display you nmlinb function? Since I am still having the same issues.

Comment: @Mikkelborchsenius `nlminb(0.015, objective = objective, lower = 0, upper = 1)$par`.  You should try after restarting R.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, it is now correct! And this case is closed.